# Why is a time component added to the date like "2023-09-30 00:00:00" after Pandas dataframe is converted to html object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python to retrieve the company balance sheet and return to the web form. The code is shown below:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from jinja2 import Markup

tickerData = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
df_company_balance_sheet = tickerData.balance_sheet
df_company_balance_sheet = df_company_balance_sheet.replace({np.nan: '--'})
print(df_company_balance_sheet)
balance_sheet_html = Markup(df_company_balance_sheet.to_html())
print(balance_sheet_html)
return balance_sheet_html
```

The data is stored in the `df_company_balance_sheet` like below:

```
                         2023-09-30       2022-09-30      2021-09-30       2020-09-30
Treasury Shares Number   4044925.0        4209150.0       4436703.0                --
Ordinary Shares Number   3001241961.0     2985714601.0    2819162059.0     2858059849.0
Share Issued             3005286886.0     2989923751.0    2823598762.0     2858059849.0
```

After using Markup to convert the data frame to an HTML object, the time component is added to the date field.  I have no idea why.

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>2023-06-30 00:00:00</th>
      <th>2022-06-30 00:00:00</th>
      <th>2021-06-30 00:00:00</th>
      <th>2020-06-30 00:00:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Ordinary Shares Number</th>
      <td>218075659.0</td>
      <td>199813184.0</td>
      <td>199347493.0</td>
      <td>198968556.0</td>
    </tr>
```

I just want the date to display in YYYY-MM-DD format